# Encrypting sensitve data in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, encryption, eclipse-plugin, encryption-asymmetric

We are developing an Eclipse plugin, in which we would like to have the some information to be packaged with the application that is sensitive and cannot be exposed to the end user, as it works something like a 'license' file. For instance, the day until which the license has been issued to the customer is one such information. So, the plugin, which is packaged as an Eclipse product, when loaded would validate against this 'license' file. We have attempted encryption techniques to encrypt the contents of the file. However, in this case, the secret key with which we are encrypting would have to be hard-coded in the plugin source. So, someone who wishes to tamper the license file can simply decompile the plugin jar and get the secret key, which would no longer remain a secret.

How to avoid this?

Is there an alternative mechanism like "asymmetric encryption" that could be used?

Comment: If the information is on the user's machine they will always be able to read it one way or another.  Being in an Eclipse plug-in is not really relevant to this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by greg-449, given that the plugin is on user's system, it will never be completely secure. There is nothing specific to Eclipse plugins. You will have generic security and Java security questions. That said, you can try to provide different layers of security.

If you want the top-level of security, I advice you to reach a company specialized to provide security (or your company security team)

As a first step, you can try to provide obfuscated plugin code. It will provide a first low layer of security.